# Spotfire - Measure distance between two points (ruler)

Tags: tibco, spotfire

Is it possible to measure the distance between two points on a map chart in Spotfire? (Like using a ruler). The scale is not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function GreatCircleDistance. This returns the shortest distance between two points, calculated on the surface of a unit sphere.

read the description of this function. There are some examples how to do this depending on whether you want the distance in kilometers or in miles.

Comment: Thanks. GreatCircleDistance works for the distance between 2 markers but isn't quite as intuitive for 2 arbitrary points (the width of a county, for example). Can you access Lat/Long for any point on the map or only for markers?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot access the lat/lon for any point on the map. Only for those markers that you have a the lat/lon coordinates. If you have the geo files from Tibco, there should be some coordinates available like min X and max X. That might help.